# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: "getLoginData" is read-only

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Destructuring from props is not working inside an async function while it's working fine if I use it using this.props.**

This is for a react-native app already in production which suddenly started giving this error 2 days back.
I've tried upgrading babel using [this](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0#babel-upgrade)

But no success so far.

If I use *this.props.getLoginData* instead, it works fine

If I use following function, it's erroneous:

```
yo = async () => { // with async
  const { getLoginData } = this.props; // error
};
```

While the following function works fine:

```
yo = () => { // without async
  const { getLoginData } = this.props;
  console.log(getLoginData); // works fine
};
```

This also works fine:

```
yo = async () => { // with async
  console.log(this.props.getLoginData); // works fine
};
```

I expect both of the scenarios to run fine.

**Please clone and run [this repo](https://github.com/NamanAulakh/read-only-bug) to reproduce this bug.**

Please find the steps to run the project and environment info in README.md.

P.S.: You will find the error in console( Press ⌘⌥I )

Comment: `: Error: “getLoginData” is read-only` seems like you are trying to reassign a value to `getLoginData` variable and why your variable name is same as your function name?

Comment: @AZ_ you are correct, but the same code was working fine 2 days back and it's written in the same manner at numerous places throughout the app, can't change at all the places

Comment: @AZ_ Created a repo to reproduce the bug

Comment: I feels weird that the variable you obtain from destructuring `this.props`, `getLoginData` has the same name as the function. Try giving it a different name eg. `const { getLoginData: getData } = this.props;`

Comment: @ElphasTori It doesn't matter, plz clone the repo and check, even with different names, the problem is same.Anyways, I've edited the question.Thanks

Comment: Although it's not exact the same, it's working on an expo snak: https://snack.expo.io/@moshfeu/test-test

Comment: @MoshFeu I got ur point, maybe it's something to do with connect.

Comment: I have the same issue. I copied your example repo into a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@makenova/da041b) and it works from the online expo environment. But when I download it, and run it locally, I get the error.

What is your build environment? OS, RN version, etc.

Comment: @makenova All this info is there in the repo( README.md )

Comment: @makenova Can you please share the working env of snack, maybe replacing local env with that might work.
Thanks.

Comment: @Napa I'm not sure what you mean. Click on the link to the snack, click the run button, and then scan the QR code with the camera on your phone. If you have the expo client on your phone, you will see it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a dependency of babel is the cause of the issue in my case.

When I look in my `package-lock.json`, and search for `plugin-transform-regenerator` I see version `7.4.5`. Locking the version to `7.4.4` by adding it to my `package.json` allows me to build without issue.

This problem would have been easier to track down if I was not ignoring my `package-lock.json`.

In summary,

`npm i -E @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.4.4`

Comment: I had the same issue, your solution worked.
Thanks.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.

Using babel version 7.4.4 didn't help me, but I've found another solution that worked - **wrapping the destructure in try-catch block**.

I still don't know why this problem happens though - will update when I do.

**________UPDATE_______**

Eventually, the solution **@makenova** offered worked (**Thanks man!**).
What I had to do is to remove all node modules + package-lock, then run

```
npm i -E @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.4.4
```

and after that run

```
npm i
```

Before that I've used **yarn** and it **didn't do the trick**.

Comment: The solution I described was to drop and lock the version of `plugin-transform-regenerator` not to use babel `7.4.4`. If you understood that and simply mis-typed what you tried, please ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

nicolo-ribaudo fixed the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/pull/377

---

An alternative solution is to force the `regenerator-transform` to use `~0.13.0` as [suggested by nicolo-ribaudo](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10193#issuecomment-511463352).

If you are using yarn, add this to your package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "regenerator-transform": "~0.13.0"
  }
```

If you are using npm:

1. Install it as a devDependency
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. Re-install dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I've a async function, when destructuring and save const show me error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: “userOperations” is read-only , this worked for me (change let by const):

https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/issues/375#issuecomment-527209159

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)